# Edit text file to add space

Tags: bash, 18.04, sed, awk

I have a text file which looks like this

```
../pool/main/a/aalib/libaa1_1.4p5-44build2_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/libaccountsservice0_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/acl_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/libacl1_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/libacl1-dev_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acpid/acpid_2.0.28-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acpi-support/acpi-support_0.142_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/adduser/adduser_3.116ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/adium-theme-ubuntu/adium-theme-ubuntu_0.3.4-0ubuntu4_all.deb
../pool/main/a/advancecomp/advancecomp_2.1-1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/adwaita-icon-theme/adwaita-icon-theme_3.28.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/aisleriot/aisleriot_3.22.5-1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/alabaster/python3-alabaster_0.7.8-1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alembic/alembic_0.9.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alembic/python3-alembic_0.9.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alembic/python-alembic_0.9.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alsa-driver/alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alsa-driver/linux-sound-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
```

I want to add space between last slash and name of deb package file e.g.

```
../pool/main/a/aalib/ libaa1_1.4p5-44build2_amd64.deb
```

I tried using sed but couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed 's_.*/_& _'
```

`s`ubstitutes everything until the last slash (`.*/`, regexes are greedy) with itself followed by a space (`&␣`) in every line.

#### Example run

Provided your text file is called `file` and resides in the current working directory:

```
$ <file sed 's_.*/_& _'
../pool/main/a/aalib/ libaa1_1.4p5-44build2_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/ accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/ gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/ libaccountsservice0_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/ acl_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/ libacl1_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/ libacl1-dev_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acpid/ acpid_2.0.28-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acpi-support/ acpi-support_0.142_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/adduser/ adduser_3.116ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/adium-theme-ubuntu/ adium-theme-ubuntu_0.3.4-0ubuntu4_all.deb
../pool/main/a/advancecomp/ advancecomp_2.1-1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/adwaita-icon-theme/ adwaita-icon-theme_3.28.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/aisleriot/ aisleriot_3.22.5-1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/alabaster/ python3-alabaster_0.7.8-1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alembic/ alembic_0.9.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alembic/ python3-alembic_0.9.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alembic/ python-alembic_0.9.3-2ubuntu1_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alsa-driver/ alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
../pool/main/a/alsa-driver/ linux-sound-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
```

To alter the file in-place, use:

```
sed -i 's_.*/_& _' file
```

Answer (score 4):

What can be done is to use pattern grouping and take advantage of greedy globbing:

```
$ echo '../pool/main/a/aalib/libaa1_1.4p5-44build2_amd64.deb' | 
> sed -r 's/(^.*\/)(.*\.deb)/\1 \2/'
../pool/main/a/aalib/ libaa1_1.4p5-44build2_amd64.deb
```

The parenthesis correspond to `\integer` items in replacement pattern. Thus first parenthesis will greedily match everything to the last slash and the second - everything after that

With input file in the question:

```
$ sed -r 's/(^.*\/)(.*\.deb)/\1 \2/' pool.txt
../pool/main/a/aalib/ libaa1_1.4p5-44build2_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/ accountsservice_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/ gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/accountsservice/ libaccountsservice0_0.6.45-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/ acl_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/ libacl1_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
<...and so on and so forth...>
```

Answer (score 1):

And for good measure an **awk** version

```
$ awk -F/ '{ OFS="/"; $NF=" "$NF; print; }' /tmp/XXXX
[...]
../pool/main/a/acl/ libacl1_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
../pool/main/a/acl/ libacl1-dev_2.2.52-3build1_amd64.deb
[...]
```

- `-F/` set the field separator to be `/`
- for each line of input, taken from `/tmp/XXXX` which contains your data

  - set output field separator to be `/` as well
  - `NF` contains the number of fields, so `$NF` is the last field
  - Set the last field to be a space string concatenated with the original last field value
  - and print